# Pascal's triangle in Python with 2-D Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, math, pascals-triangle

I'm trying write a python code that iterates over a 2-D array, the outer list should have rows in it and the inner lists should have the elements for the numbers in Pascal's triangle. I believe I'm running into issues with initializing the lists, It's been a while since I wrote in Python so any help would be appreciated.

I tried writing my code using this image
[image: https://www.mathsisfun.com/images/pascals-triangle-n-choose-k.gif]

```
from math import factorial

def binomial(x, y):
    try:
        return factorial(x) / (factorial(y) * factorial(x - y))
    except ValueError:
        return 0


def pascals_triangle(number_of_rows):
    triangle = []
    if number_of_rows <= 0:
        return None
    else:
        for row in range(number_of_rows+1):
            for column in range(row+1):
                triangle[row][column] = (binomial(row, column))
    return triangle

print(pascals_triangle(1))
```

Comment: I suggest writing `factorial(x) // (factorial(y) * factorial(x - y))`, otherwise the division will return a float instead of an int. And wouldn't it be easier to add the elements of your previous rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating `triangle` as if it's a 2D list, but it's not, and that's why you get the error. Try replacing your function with this:

```
def pascals_triangle(number_of_rows):
    triangle = []
    if number_of_rows <= 0:
        return None
    else:
        for row in range(number_of_rows+1):
            triangle.append([binomial(row, column) for column in range(row+1)])
    return triangle
```

Answer (score 1):

It is worth to build Pascal's triangle using Pascal's approach - only additions, no unnecessary factorials:

```
def PascalTriangle(n):
    res = [[1]]
    print(res[0])
    for line in range(2, n+2):
        newline = [1]
        for i in range(1, line-1):
            newline.append(res[-1][i-1] + res[-1][i])
        newline.append(1)
        res.append(newline)
        print(newline)
    return res

PascalTriangle(6)

[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
[1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]
```